# How to ask about an object's age

Tags: word-usage

If I want to know how old an item is (a bicycle, a laptop etc), is it OK to ask: "How old is your bike?" or it can only be applied to people and animals.What's the best way to phrase this question? "What's the production date?""How long have you had it?"I'll appreciate your help.

Comment: *How old* used referring to objects is just fine.

Comment: When I was 14, I had a Saturday job in a bike shop. A man came in and wanted a new saddle for a bike. Wanting to know the kind of size he needed, I asked "Is it an adult bike, sir?". He replied "I don't know really... erm, it's about  twelve years old".

Comment: The bike my current one replaced (after theft) was like Johnny Cash's Cadillac: if you had asked me how old it was I'd have had to reply "which part?"

Comment: If you feel it's weird, don't include "your bike" in your question. Simply ask "How old is this?" and your question will be automatically answered.

Comment: I would usually not know the production date. And "How long have you had it" is a completely different question. I might have bought a 20 year old car just last week.

Answer (score 1):

They're perfectly fine to use. In fact, it's the most common way of asking about the age of something, let alone the age of a person.